# linked-list insert at key function gets stuck with certain perameters?

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
struct Node {
  int key;
  Node* next;
}; 

void insert_after(Node* head, int key, int newKey )
{

  if(head != NULL){
    Node* temp = head;          
    while(temp!=NULL && key != temp->key){
        temp = head->next;
    }

    if(temp != NULL){
        Node* afterInserted = temp->next;
        Node* inserted = new Node;
        inserted->key = newKey;
        inserted->next = afterInserted;
        temp->next = inserted;
    }
  }

}
```

insert_after inserts a new node, with value "newKey" in the given linked list after the node that contains value "key". If the key isn't found, nothing should happen.

However when I run this function from main with values that are not in my linked list, the main function stops, and doesn't complete anything after the call to insert_after. Why does this happen?

My reasoning if that if the key doesn't exist in the linked list, eventually temp will be set to NULL, which breaks the "while" loop, and skips the 2nd "if" loop. Is one of these loops not breaking?

Comment: well if the head is null(ie. empty linked-list) then I want nothing to happen, which is why i didn't include an else statement. Same for the second if, because temp should be null only if the value was not found, in which case nothing should happen.

what do you mean by requirements are underspecified?

Comment: OK, you're right, the requirements make sense. I'd write it as `if (head == NULL) { return; }`, though, to keep the indentations down. And in fact you only need one NULL check, not two, since the second condition is a superset of the first.

Answer (score 0):

This while loop loops infinitely if the list has more than one node and `head->next`'s key does not match:

```
 while(temp!=NULL && key != temp->key){
        temp = head->next;
    }
```

You want to assign `temp->next` to `temp`, not `head->next`.
Thus, the code becomes:

```
 while(temp!=NULL && key != temp->key){
        temp = temp->next;
    }
```

Comment: Ahhh yes... that makes complete sense. Thank you for reviewing, I don't know how I missed that.